The phone number displayed by iOS QuickType is not refreshed
I have a UITextField for inputting mobile phone numbers and use the system's QuickType. However, when I change the phone card in my phone, the number displayed on the QuickType does not change. How should I refresh it? My system version is iOS17.2.1
quicktype
I tried restarting the phone, uninstalling the app, and reset the keyboard dictionary.
How to refresh the number
